# libphp5.so not being created after compiling and prefix directory not created

Tags: php, apache, installation

```
./configure \
    --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs \
    --prefix=/usr/local/apache/php \
    --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/apache/php
make && make install
```

I see no critical errors during the configuration, and none during installation.

Apache is installed at `/usr/local/apache`, and the apxs has been verified to be correct.

`/usr/local/apache/php` is not being created and neither is libphp5.so being generated anywhere.

I'm installing 5.2.17 on centos.

**EDIT**: Here's the full configure command:

```
./configure \
    --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs \
    --with-mysql \
    --prefix=/usr/local/apache/php \
    --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/apache/php \
    --enable-force-cgi-redirect \
    --disable-cgi \
    --with-openssl \
    --with-mcrypt \
    --with-gd \
    --with-pdo-mysql \
    --without-sqlite \
    --without-sqlite3 \
    --enable-pdo \
    --without-pdo-sqlite \
    --with-zlib \
    --with-gettext \
    --with-gdbm \
    --enable-pcnlt \
    --with-curl
```

Comment: I believe `libphp5.so` should be in `/usr/local/apache/modules`.

Comment: It's not there. There's just one file there `httpd.exp`

Comment: Why don't you use `yum` in centos?

Comment: I want to install 5.2.17, centos' latest repository store is 5.1.x. Also, I need some custom compile options such as --enable-pcntl

Comment: Make sure you clean in-between attempts, otherwise it will build from previous makes. http://melikedev.com/2010/03/24/php-compilation-make-clean/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per the php INSTALL file (which I can't fault you for not reading in its entirety... I spent an hour on google before sitting down and reading the whole thing), you need to make sure apache is installed with

```
./configure --enable-so
```

before configuring and making php with

```
./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs
```

Comment: Under osx i had to do the same: sudo ./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs

Comment: yum install httpd-devel