# different version php on command line and in apache

Tags: php, macos, apache2

I am using mac 10.8 and I have installed php 5.5. At command line php -v show version 5.5. but when I starts mac's apache server with phpinfo(), it show version 5.4.

Can anyone please help me how to make apache to use version 5.5

Thanks

Comment: How did you install php55 ? Did you compile yourself?

Comment: Have you got any previous installations of PHP, if so.. Check where your actual PHP5.5 `ini` file is, then check if `phpinfo()` corresponds with the correct loaded configuration file, if not. Let me know

Comment: the apache is read php.ini file from /etc and if i do php -i on command line it show  
'Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php/5.5
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/php.ini'
should I create a link to 5.5/php.ini in /etc directory ?

Comment: Never used homebrew, but it looks like every php installation (from homebrew-php) builds a .so php module. Please check the **LoadModule php5_module** Path in the Apache Configuration file. You'll probably have to change the Path to the php55 Module. Path to the new .so php Module should look like this: **#{HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/opt/php55[/maybe/some/dirs/here/idk]/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so**

Comment: I could not find this file on location mentioned above. I uninstalled the php55 and installed php55 xdebug and phpunit again via brew which solved the problem. Anyways thanks for your help

Answer (score 9):

1. find out the conf/httpd.conf and conf.d/*.conf
2. find the tag like this: LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
3. make the change to correct php installation folder like this: 
   LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.8/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so

This will change your php model (php version) in Apache

Search on your local desk: find / -name "libphp5.so"

Regarding the correct so file: [libphp5.so not being created after compiling and prefix directory not created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977152/libphp5-so-not-being-created-after-compiling-and-prefix-directory-not-created)

[update]

http://www.howtoforge.com/centos-5.6-php53-common-conflicts-with-php-common

1) update yum to include latest php

2) 
For 64bit systems, you can find the correct packages here: http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/5/x86_64/

For 32bit systems, the correct packages are here: http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/5/i386/

3) 
(replace to the correct URL and file name which you want to have, check it from step "2)")

rpm -Uvh http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm

rpm -Uvh http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/5/i386/ius-release-1.0-11.ius.el5.noarch.rpm

4) rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL

rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/IUS-COMMUNITY-GPG-KEY

5) yum install yum-plugin-replace

6)
You can now replace your PHP old version packages with the PHP new version packages from IUS like this:

yum replace php --replace-with php55w

You can search for further php55w packages like this:

yum search php53u

Answer (score 1):

If you uncommented the line `LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so` in httpd.conf comment it again, then add the line `export PATH=~/bin:/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH` in .bash_profile
This did the trick for me. Note: i have installed php5.5.5 via [liip](http://php-osx.liip.ch/) on OS X Mavericks