# different php versions reported

Tags: php, laravel-5, centos6

I am installing laravel and encounter some problems:

I got an error saying that I my php version is not > 5.5.9. However, when I run a `phpinfo();` test, it returns **5.5.28**. When I use putty (`php -v`), I get **5.3.3**.

I started googling (and especially on this site) and one of the solutions was to change the httpd.config file (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/1009). However, adding LoadModule `php5_module    /usr/local/opt/php55/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` does not work (there is not such a file). What else should I try? My OS is CentOS 6.5.

Comment: Don't you have php-fpm installed ? Try `php-fpm -v`. Maybe your apache server use fpm.

Comment: Could be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554831/different-version-php-on-command-line-and-in-apache

Comment: @VincentDecaux php-fpm: command nout found

Comment: @GoatMaster I don't have this line `LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so` in my httpd.config file

Comment: You should place that line in your httpd.conf file and point it to the correct php location. Then restart Apache server.

Comment: Anyway, php 5.5.28 is < 5.5.9.

Comment: @GoatMaster What is the commeand to find the correct php location?

Comment: It is possible to install multiple PHP versions on a single server, but it tends to lead to confusing issues like this, so I suggest removing the old one and just sticking with one version.

Comment: @Unex 5.5.28 is NOT < 5.5.9

Comment: @shock_gone_wild you'll have to explain why it's not because numbers aren't in your favor.

Comment: look at http://php.net/releases/  php 5.5.9 was released 6 Feb 2014  and 5.5.28 was released 06 Aug 2015 ( it's even the newes 5.5 release right now )  and anyway... 28 is BIGGER than 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this [link](http://www.servermom.org/upgrade-php-53-54-55-centos/1534/) helped me to solve my problem. Hope it does help others as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about CentOS, but on Debian/Ubuntu, `php5` (for the web server) and `php5-cli` (for the command line) are two different packages and can be installed independently. I've never done it before, but I can imagine it would be possible to install two different versions of PHP.

It appears that this is the state you are in: your version of `php5-cli` is 5.3.3. When you install Laravel using `composer`, you are using the command line. Thus, it is picking up `5.3.3` as the version and complaining that it's too low. It seems that Laravel is assuming that the versions of both packages are the same.

I can see two possible solutions:

1. uninstall PHP and reinstall it. To be on the safe side, I'd uninstall everything & reinstall it. You could fiddle around & try to bring `php5-cli` up to the correct version, but that would probably be more trouble than it's worth.
2. install Laravel by downloading the source and unzipping it into the correct location. This also seems like it might be a lot of work. I'm not sure how much configuration the Laravel install script does - you'll have to figure it out & do it by hand. But in this case, Laravel *should* run, since PHP for the web server meets the minimum requirements; however, you're probably going to have trouble using `composer` to install dependencies...